# PHP and MongoDB - empty result with $near

Tags: php, mongodb, database, nosql

I want to get entries of a point (lat,lng) which are close to this point.

I created one entry in the mongodb database.

When I search it via the find method -> works fine.

When I try to search it via $near -> empty!

PHP:

```
    try{        
$lnglat = array(floatval($latitude),floatval($longitude));
$query = array('loc' => array('$near' => $lnglat));
//search 1
$results = $pointsCollection->find($query)->limit(100);

 while($results->hasNext()){
    $user = $results->getNext();
    var_dump($user['Title']);
};  
    }catch(Exception $e){
        var_dump($e);
        return false;
    }
```

I dont get an error message or anything else.

The latitude and longitude values are the same with the entry in the database but it still seems like it has not found anything.

Comment: can you show what you get back when you search via find?  you have a geospatial index on this collection on the loc field, right?

Comment: Perhaps the query is missing $maxDistance operator? `db.legacy2d.find(
   { location : { $near : [ -73.9667, 40.78 ], $maxDistance: 0.10 } }
)`